# How to jest.mock simple-git/promise

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am testing to mock `simple-git/promise` checkout function and I am not successful. this is what I have done

```
    jest.mock('simple-git/promise', () => {
      return {
        checkout: async () => {
          Promise.resolve();
        }
      }
    });
```

can someone help?

Comment: Mocking modules can get hairy depending on the library. Small suggestion as a start, don't implement checkout, use a jest mock
  `jest.mock('simple-git/promise', () => ({
        checkout: jest.fn()
      }));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unit test example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import git from 'simple-git/promise';

function main() {
  git().checkout('https://github.com/user/repo.git');
}

export default main;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import main from './';
import git from 'simple-git/promise';

jest.mock('simple-git/promise', () => {
  const mGit = {
    checkout: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mGit);
});

describe('60018953', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    main();
    expect(git().checkout).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/user/repo.git');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/60018953/index.test.ts
  60018953
    ✓ should pass (8ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.24s, estimated 13s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60018953